# Slowing mouse speed

Tags: wpf, performance, events, mouse, acceleration

Any ideas on how I can slow down the mouse speed in a wpf application. Google didn't come up with anything. Should this be dealt with native events from Win32.

Comment: Are you talking about slowing the mouse speed over your particular control/window, or are you talking about a system-wide change a la the Mouse control panel?

Comment: [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showpost.php?s=800d0b57a1e020ecd4f6a58a0dd5487c&p=1592814&postcount=2)

Comment: awesome thank you, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: it worked, but system wide, any suggestion as to how to constrain it to the window? I guess it would work, to check if the mouse is inside the window slow it down, if it is outside the window return it to normal, but then there would need to be a way to find out what the normal is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showpost.php?s=800d0b57a1e020ecd4f6a58a0dd5487c&p=1592814&postcount=2)

SPI_GETMOUSESPEED = 112 decimal
SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 113 decimal
[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

OnAppStart -> get system current mouse speed
OnMouseEnter -> set to slow
OnMouseLeave -> set to system
OnAppShutdown -> set to system

EDIT
[Additional Reference](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/netfxbcl/thread/c3e47cdf-cabc-46d1-9ae5-66e42a769cee)